# Specify php.ini in phpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I've set-up my PHP environment with the `$PHPRC` environment variable to point to the `php.ini`. Since `$PHPRC` is set during bash start-up, it's never set for phpStorm. This means phpStorm is using the wrong `php.ini` for CLI. This is especially anoying since I do a lot of PHPUnit testing.

How can I make phpStorm using the same `php.ini`? I'd prefer to have a possibility to specifiy the php.ini somehow in phpStorm, but I cannot find such an option.

In case this matters, I'm on OSX using MAMP PRO 2.1.

Comment: I think you need to do something like this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57385/where-are-system-environment-variables-set-in-mountain-lion (i.e. set that variable via `.plist` file) ... or use **default** php.ini location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this:

1.: Create your run configuration for the test

[image]

2.: Add your `php.ini` path to your [command line/interpreter options](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

[image]