# Class 'mysqli' not found PHP v5.6.7

Tags: php, mysqli, phpstorm

On my Windows 7 machine, with PHP v5.6.7 and MySQL v5.6.23, and using PHPStorm 8, I am attempting to instantiate a mysqli object. When I try, I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in...
```

I have also run this test, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012539/class-mysqli-not-found):

```
 if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
      echo 'no mysqli :(';
 } else {
      echo 'we gots it';
 }
```

The output is:

```
no mysqli :(
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434305/mysqli-class-not-found-using-percona-php5-fpm-nginx-phalcon) that this problem is sometimes caused when it looks for the mysqli class within a namespace. I changed my code to correct this, but the issue persists

```
$mysqli = new \mysqli($host, $userName, $password, $database);
```

I read that this problem is sometimes caused when the mysqli extension is not enabled. However, I am using PHP version 5.6.7, and the mysqli extension is enabled by default on versions 5.3 and newer (according to [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php)).

Just to be sure, I have verified that `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` have `extension_dir = "C:/PHP/php-5.6.7/ext"` and have the semi-colon removed from the lines:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

[Additional information]
I found a test to run and according to phpinfo() it is not loading a configuration file:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
```

For some reason, the PHPStorm web server is not looking for php.ini in the right place?

I have this setting in the "Interpreter options" per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796280/specify-php-ini-in-phpstorm):

```
--php-ini C:\PHP\php-5.6.7\php.ini
```

I have verified that this is the correct path.

Comment: I think the php.ini-development files are just templates, you should copy the one you want to base your configuration off and place it as appropriate for where PHP will look for the actual file; `php.ini`

Comment: Have you restarted all services after making any changes to system files? Plus, have you tried `$mysqli = new mysqli ...` without the slash?

Comment: scrowler, thank you for the suggestion. I've done that, but there seems to be an error parsing the php.ini file. I am doing some more research before editing my question.

Fred -ii-, I believe PHP doesn't have a running process that needs to be restarted. I believe PHPStorm automatically restarts its internal webserver between runs. I will try rebooting the comp to make sure. I have, indeed tried it with and without the \.

Comment: I'm running on Wamp and I remember I had to reboot my system in order to make it work after installing it. Could be the same here.

Comment: I was just going to mention if you went through their checklist https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/php-built-in-web-server.html and point #4.

Comment: Does `php -i` say mysqli is enabled?

Comment: awons, yes, it does report enabled

Comment: Fred -ii- I did, indeed take those steps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

scrowler and Michael Bush pointed out the answer in comments above. I thought I'd create an answer for it for the benefit of someone viewing the thread. Thanks, scrowler and Michael Bush.

The `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` files are templates. In order to have effect, one of them needs to be copied and renamed `php.ini`.

Comment: If scrowler or Michael Bush wish to post this an an answer before tommorrow, I'll "accept" yours instead.

Answer (score 5):

Have you added the PHP installation directory to you environment path

- right click on my computer from the start menu
- click on properties
- find advanced system settings
- click on environment variables
- under system variables find PATH add C:\php replacing C:\php with your PHP
  installation directory; *** remember the path separator

Also check this entry in your php.ini

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"
```

Comment: Yes, the php installation is on the system path.

Comment: I believe you need to edit your php.ini and change extension_dir from extension_dir = "ext" to extension_dir = "c:/php/ext" or what ever your path is

Comment: can you also confirm that you have copied and renamed either php.ini-development or php.ini-production to php.ini

Comment: can I see the output of phpinfo()

Comment: I have to concentrate on homework for a while. I will get back to this when I can.

Comment: @DonSubert How did the homework go?

Comment: I assume fine, as I graduated 6 years ago.