# How do you set the path to the php.ini file in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

How do you specify the path to the `php.ini` file in PhpStorm?

I am trying to build run configurations for Built-in Web Server and PHPUnit, but I cannot figure out how to specify the path of the php.ini file.

The only resource that I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796280/specify-php-ini-in-phpstorm), but it does not appear to work for current versions of PhpStorm.

I have set the interpreter options to `--php-ini C:\PHP\php-5.6.7\php.ini`. This is the correct path to the file. However, when I get the `phpinfo()`, it reports:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
```

(This is related to another question that I asked, but it is specific enough, I think, that a new thread is warranted.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working just fine using `-c` for specifying path to custom `php.ini`

[image]

**P.S.**
Ignore the small path difference -- it's because `E:\Projects\php\` is a symlink to `E:\Projects\php56\` and I did not bother to use "real" path.

**P.P.S.**
Works for both local "PHPUnit" and "PHP Script" types of Run/Debug configurations.

---

I believe that currently it's not possible to provide path to custom `php.ini` for built-in web server as it uses your default local PHP Interpreter and that has no options for providing custom parameters (except those passed via `-d` option)

Comment: When you say "it uses your default local PHP Interpreter" are you saying that it uses the php.ini file in the php root directory?

Comment: Yes -- and other standard locations  -- whatever comes first (e.g. `C:\Windows`, `PHPRC` environment variable etc -- in order as described in [manual](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)).

Comment: When I don't specify anything, it only looks in C:\Windows. It ignores the php.ini file in my php root

Comment: No clue then -- for me the Built-In web server takes php.ini from the folder where php's executable used for that is located. I suggest to check all those possible locations (env variable & registry keys) -- maybe it has keys but points to a wrong/non-existent path. You may also try adding path to your php's home into `PATH`.

Comment: Another idea is: place your php.ini in such predefined location (e.g. `C:\Windows`) where php can find it there (should find). And if another config is required for PHPUnit -- you know how to provide such config now. P.S. Another alternative is to use proper web server (Apache or IIS)